# How to fix the CSS/HTML image aspect ratio fixed across different monitors?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I use the following codes, the aspect ratio of my square-shaped image (1:1 aspect ratio) changes across different devices (different types of monitors/mobile phones)? When I say changes, on some devices it's a perfect square image as I'd expect but on some devices it becomes a rectangle. Does anyone know how to fix this? I want it to have the original aspect ratio.

> 

```
<div class="col-xl-3"> <img src="images/myimg.jpg" style="width: auto; height: 310px; margin-top: -190px; padding-left: 50px;"
            class="img-fluid" alt="Placeholder image"> </div>
```

> 

```
<div class="col-xl-3"> <img src="images/myimg.jpg" style="width: 310px; height: 310px; margin-top: -190px; padding-left: 50px;"
            class="img-fluid" alt="Placeholder image"> </div>
```

> .img-fluid {
> max-width: 100%,
> height: auto
> }

It's a static website hosted on github pages.

Try different options. I was expecting it to preserve its original aspect ratio.

Comment: can you add the image link for reference too?

Comment: Could you describe why you have given the img a max width when you have set its height to a fixed value?

Comment: Because I use the same template for different images with different settings. I can always create a new one. But would it affect?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by giving `width` & `height` `100%` to the image and limiting the parent div. By this it will always take the width and height available to it but not exceeding the `max-width` & `max-height` regardless of the device.

```css
.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 310px;
  max-height: 310px;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container"> <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495615080073-6b89c9839ce0?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=906&q=80" class="img-fluid" alt="Placeholder image"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't work for some reason. 

Can margin and padding options I provide affect this? 
margin-top: -190px; padding-left: 50px

Comment: I dont think it would affect aspect ratio after you have given fixed width & height to it. May I know the reason why are you using such values for margin & padding?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.myImg {
  display: block;
  max-width:120px;
  max-height:210px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>This photo is originally 500 pixels, but should get resized by the CSS</p>
<img class="myImg" width="400" height="400" src="https://i.imgur.com/nOBDgBx.png">
```